# Add record in table using manipulating query

Tags: java, collections

When I want to load the data from the database and want to display in a table by manipulating query like the following example

```java
public class LapRekapInput extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private Connection koneksi;
    private Date tglSurat;
    private String varSub1 = "N";
    private String varSub2 = "N";
    private String varSub3 = "N";
    private String varSub4 = "N";
    private PreparedStatement ps;

    private DynamicTableModel<LapRekInput> tableModel;

    /**
     * Creates new form LapRekapitulasiInput
     */
    public LapRekapInput() {
        koneksi = DatabaseUtilitas.getkoneksi();
        initComponents();
        tableModel = new DynamicTableModel<>(LapRekInput.class);
        tablelapRekap.setDynamicModel(tableModel);

    }

    private void LoadLapRekInput(){
       tglSurat = jDateChooser1.getDate();
            if(jComboBoxSubdit.getSelectedItem().equals("Subdit Mogok Kerja Dan Deteksi Dini")){
                varSub1 = "Y";
            }else if(jComboBoxSubdit.getSelectedItem().equals("Subdit Penyelesaian Perselisihan Hubungan Industrial")){
                varSub2 = "Y";
            }else if(jComboBoxSubdit.getSelectedItem().equals("Subdit Kelembagaan PPHI")){
                varSub3 = "Y";
            }else if(jComboBoxSubdit.getSelectedItem().equals("Subag Tata Usaha")){
                varSub4 = "Y";
            }


         String sql = "select NoAgenda, asalSurat, tglSurat, NoSurat, Perihal from tahap2 "
                    + " WHERE tglSurat = '"+new java.sql.Date(tglSurat.getTime())+"' "
                    + "and dtrsknKpd1 IN ('"+varSub1+"') "
                    + " and dtrsknKpd2 IN ('"+varSub2+"') "
                    + " and dtrsknKpd3 IN ('"+varSub3+"') "
                    + " and dtrsknKpd4 IN ('"+varSub4+"') ";


          try {
            ps = koneksi.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

                List<LapRekInput> list = (List<LapRekInput>) rs;
                for(LapRekInput rekInput : list){
                    tableModel.add(rekInput);
                }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be
>   cast to java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to java.util.List

Since you are  converting `ResultSet` to `List<LapRekInput>`. Such type casting is not possible. Since there is no relation between these two.

The way to retrieve values from `rs` is

```
List<LapRekInput> list = new List<LapRekInput>();

while(rs.next())
{

    LapRekInput obj = new LapRekInput();
    //now add values from rs to obj with its setter methods
    obj.setmethod1(rs.getString(1));
    obj.setmethod2(rs.getString(2));
    --------------------------------
    //now add this obj to list
   list.add(obj);

}

for(LapRekInput rekInput : list){
     tableModel.add(rekInput);
}
```